# Incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <dos.h>
using namespace std;

class Dir
{
public:
    char* cat;
    Dir()
    {
        cout << "(C:/*)\n";
        cat = new char[50];
        cin >> cat;
    }

    void virtual ShowFiles()
    {
    }

};


class Inside : public Dir
{
public:
    void virtual ShowFiles()
    {
        HANDLE hSearch;
        WIN32_FIND_DATA pFileData;

        hSearch = FindFirstFile(cat, &pFileData);
        if (hSearch != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            do
            {
                //  if ((pFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
                cout << pFileData.cFileName << "\n";
            } while (FindNextFile(hSearch, &pFileData));
            FindClose(hSearch);
    }
};
int main()
{
    Dir *obj1[2];
    obj1[1] = new Inside;
    obj1[1]->ShowFiles();
    return 0;
}
```

So I have a program, I need to show with dynamic char cat all file in directory, but it is compilable in Borland C++ but in Visual Studio 15 + Resharper it doesn't work. **Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error (active) argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"**

Comment: Not related to your error, but `cin >> cat` is a buffer overflow waiting to happen. Use `cin >> setw(50) >> cat` instead. Or switch to `std::string` and `std::getline()`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To compile your code in Visual C++ you need to use Multi-Byte char WinAPI functions instead of Wide char ones.

Set **Project -> Properties -> Advanced (or. General for older versions) -> Character Set** option to **Use Multi-Byte Character Set**

[also see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWRDr.png)

Comment: Or, stop using the `TCHAR` based APIs and use the `char` based APIs instead (`FindFirstFileA()` and `WIN32_FIND_DATAA`).  Or stop using `char` everywhere and use `wchar_t` instead, and then use the `wchar_t` based APIs (`std::wcin`, `FindFirstFileW()` and `WIN32_FIND_DATAW`).

Comment: Already tried it, when I see problem first of all I search it on stack then I try to solve it by itself and if I can't do it I ask it.

Comment: All alternatives provided by Remy above should work also. Пожалуйста :)

Comment: I’d recommend using utf-8 (multi-byte) everywhere you can.  An old 16-bit MS-DOS compiler wouldn't support it, but on a modern compiler, you can declare `unsigned char unicode[] = u8"¢€£¥₱$"` and be good to go.  Or `char16_t unicode[] =  u"¢€£¥₱$"` to use the wide API.

Comment: @Lorehead On Windows, UTF-16 everywhere is more practical, unless you like having to convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16 all the time.

Comment: @immibis Well, utf-8 source files are more practical if only because they take up half the space and work in more compilers.  If you want to use utf-16 everywhere, you can do it with `char16_t` and `u"This will be in UTF-16 encoding."`, even in a utf-8 source file. On other systems, `wchar_t` might be ucs-32, but `wchar_t` and `L"A wide-char string."` is portable to POSIX.

Comment: Still cannot convert `const char16_t *` to `LPCSTR`.

Comment: @SummerSun `LPCSTR` is a string of 8-byte chars, not 16-byte. And I suppose `const char16_t *` is a string of 16-byte chars. You need either to use `LPCWSTR` instead of `LPCSTR`, or convert your string to `LPCSTR` using `WideCharToMultiByte` function.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev thank you, I switch from `CreateDirectoryA` to `CreateDirectoryW` and issue got fixed.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019 this is now mapped to: Project -> Properties -> Advanced -> Character -> Use Multi-Byte Character Set

Comment: Does someone knows how can I set "Use Multi-byte" using VSCODE?

Comment: @Shrout1 I have tried this, but it show garbage output... Sometimes, I can't even run the application as I see some antivirus library, awshook.dll shown.

Answer (score 14):

The answer was absolutely incorrect. It's unclear why it got votes up.

Comment: It might not fit with your question but whosoever searches this error ends up at this post (just like me) so, it might help others

Comment: I know this would work, but I'd love to have an explanation of why it is necessary. Does it have to do with some change/peculiarity with newer versions of Visual Studio?

Comment: Uhh, does this new version actually work? (As in shows the correct text, not just compiles?) LPCWSTR is for wide characters, but yours are narrow.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It does not work. MSM likely compiles non-unicode config and ignores the warnings. The simple code `#include <windows.h>

int main() {
  MessageBoxW(NULL, (LPCWSTR) "Dialog creation failed! Aborting..", "Error", MB_OK);
}
`outputs hieroglyphs in the title and body and is UB since LPCWSTR do not end with wchar_t zeroes.

Answer (score 9):

Another way to come by this issue, is to use the `L`macro in front of your string.

```
MessageBox(NULL, L"Dialog creation failed! Aborting..", L"Error", MB_OK);
```

See: [What does the 'L' in front a string mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384118/what-does-the-l-in-front-a-string-mean-in-c)

or

[L prefix for strings in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086817/l-prefix-for-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

you can use **wchar_t**

```
class Dir
{
public:
    wchar_t* cat;
Dir()
{
    wcout << "(C:/*)\n";
    cat = new wchar_t[50];
    wcin >> cat;
}

    void virtual ShowFiles()
    {
    }

};
```

In **Visual Studio 2013 and later**, the MFC libraries for multi-byle character encoding (**MBCS**) will be provided as an add-on to Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

It will work for any settings:

```
#include <tchar.h>

MessageBox(NULL, _T("Dialog creation failed! Aborting.."), _T("Error"), MB_OK);
```