# How to use generic function GetDriveType

Tags: c, windows, winapi, unicode, ansi

I have a C app that I need to compile in `Windows`. And I am really unable to wrap my head around the `UNICODE` and `ANSI` concept in `Windows`

I want to use `GetDriveType` function and there are 2 variables `A` and `W`. There is also a note [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypea) saying that `GetDriveType` is an alias to both and will select either based on some pre-processor.

But how should I call this function ?

This is what I am trying:

```
const TCHAR* path = "C:\\Users\\";
const TCHAR* trailing_slash = "\\";
size_t requiredSize = mbstowcs(NULL, path, 0);
TCHAR* win_path = (char*)malloc((requiredSize + 2) * sizeof(char));
UINT driveType = 0;
strncpy(win_path, path, requiredSize + 1);
strncat(win_path, trailing_slash, 2);

printf("Checking path: %s\n", win_path);

driveType = GetDriveType(win_path);
wprintf(L"Drive type is: %d\n", driveType);
if (driveType == DRIVE_FIXED)
    printf("Success\n");
else
    printf("Failure\n");
return 0;
```

It produces the result

```
Checking path: C:\Users\
Drive type is: 1
Failure
```

If I replace `GetDriveType` with `GetDriveTypeA` it returns the correct value `3` and succeeds.

I tried another variant too

```
size_t requiredSize = mbstowcs(NULL, path, 0);
uint32_t drive_type = 0;
const wchar_t *trailing_slash = L"\\";

wchar_t *win_path = (wchar_t*) malloc((requiredSize + 2) * sizeof(wchar_t));

/* Convert char* to wchar* */
size_t converted = mbstowcs(win_path, path, requiredSize+1);

/* Add a trailing backslash */
wcscat(win_path, trailing_slash);

/* Finally, check the path */
drive_type = GetDriveType(win_path);
```

I see this warning:

```
'function' : incompatible types - from 'wchar_t *' to 'LPCSTR'
```

So, which one to use ? How is it generic ? The path I will be reading is from an environment variable on Windows

What is `TCHAR` and `wchar_t` etc. ? I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001284/incompatible-with-parameter-of-type-lpcwstr), but could not understand much

This Microsoft [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings) says

> Depending on your preference, you can call the Unicode functions explicitly, such as SetWindowTextW, or use the macros

So is it Ok to use `wchar_t` everywhere and call `GetDriveTypeW` directly ?

Comment: Yes, you can ignore the `TCHAR` stuff and use `wchar_t` everywhere. But if you do use `TCHAR` the string literals need to be wrapped with the `_T(x)` or `_TEXT(x)` macros, e.g. `_T("C:\\Users\\")`. If `TCHAR` is a `wchar_t`, that will prepend the `L` prefix to the string literal.

Comment: So basically the second version of my code is OK ? I should use `GetDriveTypeW` instead of `GetDriveType` ? Why does it give a warning though ?

Answer (score 2):

Back in the mid-90s you had Windows 95/98/ME that did not support Unicode and NT4/2000/XP that did. You could create source code that could compile with or without Unicode support just by changing the `UNICODE` define.

This type of code looks like this:

```
UINT type = GetDriveType(TEXT("c:\\"));
```

There is no function named `GetDriveType`, 99% of all functions that take a string parameter in Windows have two versions, in this case `GetDriveTypeA` and `GetDriveTypeW`.

Inside the Windows header files you have code that looks like this:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define GetDriveType GetDriveTypeW
#else
#define GetDriveType GetDriveTypeA
#endif
```

If UNICODE is defined before including windows.h the above code expands to:

```
UINT type = GetDriveTypeW(L"c:\\");
```

and if not:

```
UINT type = GetDriveTypeA("c:\\");
```

These days most applications should use Unicode. Whether you should use `wchar_t`/`WCHAR` and call `GetDriveTypeW` directly or still rely on the defines is a style question. There might be situations where you need to force the A or W function and [that is OK](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211210-00/?p=106021) as well.

The same applies to the C library with the `_TEXT` macro and the _tcs functions except that those are controlled by the `_UNICODE` define.

If you get a warning about incompatible string types then you are calling the wrong function or you have not added `#define UNICODE` (and `_UNICODE`). If you are compiling cross platform code intended for Unix you might have to convert from `char*` to a wide string in some places.

See also:

- [TEXT vs. _TEXT vs. _T, and UNICODE vs. _UNICODE](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040212-00/?p=40643)